# NoReverseMatch error when returning Respose object in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an Instagram clone.

Clicking the follow button calls ajax.

My view def post saves "follows" and returns the Response object whose data is true/false values for whether or not the user was previously followed.

error message

```
‘django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profile' 
with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried’
```

views.py

```py
class ProfileListView(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    """User post list"""
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'insta/profile_list.html'
    serializer_class = InstaSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        target = kwargs.get('username')
        try:
            target_user = USER.objects.get(username=target)
            response = Insta.objects.filter(owner__username=target)
            return Response({'posts': response, 'target_user': target_user})
        except USER.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('insta:dashboard'), status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        followed_user = get_object_or_404(USER, username=kwargs.get('username'))

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            follower_user = request.user
            if followed_user == follower_user:
                raise PermissionError('Unable to follow yourself')
            else:
                if follower_user in followed_user.followers.all():
                    followed_user.followers.remove(follower_user)
                    return Response({
                        'follow_exist': False
                    })
                else:
                    follower_user.follows.add(followed_user)
                    return Response({
                        'follow_exist': True
                    })
        else:
            return redirect('insta/login')
```

urls.py

```py
path('<username>/', insta_profile, name='profile'),
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url 'insta:profile' username=target_user.username %}',
        data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.follow_exist) {
                $this.attr('class', 'btn btn-outline-secondary');
                $this.text('cancel follow')
            } else {
                $this.attr('class', 'btn btn-primary');
                $this.text('follow')
            }
         },
         error: function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
         }
});
```

Could you tell me why this happens?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think **target_user.username** is getting blank in ajax URL

Comment: Maybe try this instead: `url: '{% url 'profile' target_user.username %}',` also `insta_profile` where does it point at in your urls?

Comment: Please show the view where you render the template that contains the ajax.

Comment: Username seems to be passing correctly when i debug.

Comment: have you added **app_name = 'insta'** in urls.py

Comment: `with arguments '('',)'` means that either `target_user` is unset or `target_user.username` is unset, or that the error is coming from a different `{% url %}` tag that you haven't shown.

Comment: when is this happening? when you actually click on the 'follow' button? or when you render the template where this button should be shown?

Comment: i added whole class view

Comment: it happens when return Response

Comment: The argument passed to post function successfully. There is no error before return Response, I guess.

Comment: You can not return a redirect with a 404, since a redirect has status code 302 (or 301, depending on whether it is permanent or not).

Answer (score 0):

add this at your exception

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('insta:dashboard', args=(username,), status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

instead of

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('insta:dashboard'), status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't raise DoesNotExist